# Validating if object data is "true" and retrieving relevant data if so

Tags: javascript, object

I have a problem to solve using some data from an object. The data could take a few forms and may or may not exist in the first place. For example

```
things : {
   oranges: true,
   apples : false
}
```

but it could equally be:

```
things : {
   oranges: false,
   apples : false
}
```

or maybe `things` doesn't even exist

I need to:

1) Determine that `things` exists

2) Determine that `things` contains further keys

These two statements need to be verified in one callable function e.g `thingsHasData()`

3) If `things` does have data, is any of the data set to `true`?

This also needs to be a callable function e.g `fruitsIsTrue()`

4) Return the key for one of the true values

`trueFruit()` - this should only return one key, but it doesn't matter which *(it shouldn't ever have two true values as per business rules but it's more of a fallback to just return one if for some reason it does)*

So I've been able to get the key of a `true` key-value pair using the following:

```
var thingsList = {
    things : {
           oranges: false,
           apples : true
        }
    }
var trueFruit = Object.keys(thingsList).filter(function(key) {
    return thingsList[key];
});

return thingsList[0];
```

This correctly returns `apples` and only apples so it works for point *4* but not the others, and I feel like there is a better way to do this not having to rely on repeating the same `.filter` in a few different functions. Ideas?

Comment: The question seems a bit broad, could you be more specific on what the problem is?

Comment: @Daan what makes it too broad? I've given the code and asked for the best way to get the results required by the three functions specified but without repeating the same `.filter` query several times

Comment: I mean that there are a lot of questions in one question. I think asking each question seperately will give you some necessary answers that bring you towards your end goal.

Comment: @Daan I'm not allowed to delete the question any more so I will have to create smaller duplicates

Answer (score 1):

To check if the Object `things` exist, you can use the following code:

```
if (typeof things != "undefined") {
    // It exists!
}
```

To check if an object has any children, check `Object.keys(things).length > 0`.

So the check for 1) and 2) would look like:

```
let things = {
   oranges: true,
   apples: false
}

if (typeof things != "undefined") {
    // It exists!
    if (Object.keys(things).length > 0) {
        // It has children!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take functions and for a `true` value, use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
function thingsHasData(object) {
    return 'things' in object;
}

function fruitsIsTrue(object) {
    return 'things' in object && Object.values(object.things).some(Boolean);
}

function trueFruit(object) {
    return 'things' in object && Object.keys(object.things).find(k => object.things[k]);
}

var a = {},
    b = { things: {} },
    c = { things: { oranges: true, apples : false } },
    d = { things: { oranges: false, apples : false } };

[a, b, c, d].forEach(o => console.log(
    thingsHasData(o),
    fruitsIsTrue(o),
    trueFruit(o)
));
```

Comment: Hmmm. Isn’t there a lot of repetitive stuff in there? It will check for things in object again and again.

Comment: it depends on the use. the question taks about three functions and not ig the function are related to each other, but it could be to write it with dependent functions.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var thingsList = {
    things : {
        oranges: false,
        apples : true
    },
    things2 : {
        oranges: true,
        apples : true
    }
};

function validateThings(things) {
    // (1) checks for a falsy value of things
    if (!things) {
        return false;
    }
    var keys = Object.keys(things);
    // (2) checks if things has keys
    if (!keys.length) {
        return false;
    }
    // (3) then it checks for every single keys value if it is truthy
    for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        if (things[keys[i]]) {
            // (4) return this value — all tests passed
            return things[keys[i]];
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(validateThings(thingsList.notInList));
console.log(validateThings(thingsList.things));
console.log(validateThings(thingsList.things2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const thingsHasData = arg => (arg.things && Object.keys(arg.things).length>0) ? true : false;
const trueFruit = arg => {
    if (!arg.things) return;
    let fruitIndex = null;
    let fruitValues = Object.values(arg.things);
    fruitValues.forEach((value, index) => {
        if (value) fruitIndex = Object.keys(arg.things)[index];
    });
    return fruitIndex;
}
```